# Were the main characters not fired?

Tags: plot-explanation, role-models-2008

In the movie [Role Models](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0430922/), the main characters start off as energy drink salesmen. After a harsh breakup, their next couple sales pitches go terribly - to the point where they are telling school children to do drugs, etc. They also destroy or damage company and public property (the Minotaur vehicle, etc.) while on the job and are on the hook for jail time as a result unless they complete community service.

As far as I remember, no further mention of their jobs is made. At the end of the movie, they have access to the same company vehicle they were driving before. They clearly had to enter some kind of access code to get the truck.

Were they not fired?? How did they have access to the company vehicle still? They must have had the correct access code, and keys to the vehicle they previously wrecked.

Comment: If they had access to the company car then they were not fired, isn't that the proof? There's no question here

Comment: Does it even matter? What makes you believe they were fired? Realistically, you'd think they would, but it doesn't even matter in the context of this film.